# Undo/Redo for iOS Painting App

Tags: ios, drawing, opengl-es-2.0, paint, undo-redo

I have been doing research on what the best way to achieve undo/redo functionality is for a painting app. I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS. The most popular approach seems to be to save a list of commands and VBOs to re-generate the painting to its previous state (Memento design structure). The other approach is to take graphical snapshots after each drawing action and revert to these snapshots on undo.

I have a problem with both approaches:

1) Memento - after a long list of actions, especially computationally intensive flood fill algorithms, the undo/redo functionally will get very slow and intensive.

2) Snapshots - after a long list of actions these snapshot will start to take up a lot of memory, especially if in raw state.

I was wondering if anybody has found a solution that works well for this situation, or perhaps somebody here has an idea how to optimize the above approaches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to try a hybrid approach, where I save a bitmap snapshot every 10-15 actions, and use command lines to restore individual actions past the snapshots. A more in depth answer is offered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944758/2303367

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way around limiting the number of steps that are undoable. You will always need *some* amount of memory to capture either the previous state, or the state change, for each undoable operation.

The [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) actually seems like the much more natural fit than the Memento to handle undo/redo. Using this, you will only store information about the specific changes for each operation. Which can still be substantial depending on the operation, but I think it can be much more targeted than blindly saving entire object states with a Memento.